# WYSIWYG not appearing for custom content type

Tags: 6, nodes

I am working on a re-work of Drupalerp (D6), as I found so many problems with it...but have run into an odd issue. As drupalerp creates it's extra content types programatically, I am unsure if it is doing it correctly. For content types created in the GUI, the Drupal way, I can get the Wysiwyg to appear.

In the node_type table the drupal nodes that work have 'node' in the module column, and has_body = 1. The erp ones have their individual module names instead of 'node'. If I switch the module to node for those ones, I get wysiwyg, but of course lose the custom programmed handling of those types.

So my question is, does that have to be 'node' in the module column of node_type in order to get wysiwyg, or is there another element missing from the programming of those custom types?

Comment: What kind of wysiwyg module are you using? wysiwyg.module depends on the input type but others allow to configure it based on the textarea name/id.

Comment: Yes, was using the Wysiwyg.module...it obviously needs to be running through the node module. I have ditched Wysiwyg/tinyMCE, and gone to straight CKEDITOR which works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the CKeditor module, you can apply the editor to any textarea on the site. However, it doesn't apply this by default. You have to set up the settings to either appear on ALL textareas or selected ones only.

Underneath every textarea, it gives you an element ID which you can use to isolate specific ones and get the editor to appear.

Assuming you're using CKeditor of course. :o)

Comment: I have ditched Wysiwyg/tinyMCE, and gone to straight CKEDITOR which works!

Comment: Good stuff... I really like the Wysiwyg module, but tinyMCE is rubbish!

Answer (score 0):

I know that wysiwyg is related to input filters, are these available on the body (if there is one) of the custom nodes?

Comment: yeah, good call...but yes they are all set to use Full HTML. I put the Better Formats module in to make sure that was the case, too. I'm thinking I probably need to start picking apart an existing 3rd-party module that does let the wysiwyg work, to see what is different architecturally.